# Hystrix how to send a clean request, without null

Tags: java, hystrix

I am using Hystrix for API request in my application.

Is it possible to configure Hystrix to send a cleaned up version of my request to an API. I mean, not sending the fields which are null?

The background to this question:
I am using a service which has an openapi json file to generate the client. If I generate the client and use it for my requests it also sends the optional fields as null. But the service does not allow on some fields to be null. If I do not send the null fields, everything works fine.